# New to learning TestNG, getting an "org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot instantiate class" error in Java code

Tags: java, testing, testng

Trying to learn about TestNG Framework but encountered an error which says it is unable to instantiate the class

made a class SomeClassToTest with one public method which finds out the sum of two numbers
made another test class to learn about annotations in testNG

Code for TestAnnotation class

```
package testclasses;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import appcode.SomeClassToTest;

public class TestAnnotation {

    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {

        SomeClassToTest obj = new SomeClassToTest();
        int result = obj.sumNumbers(1, 2);

        System.out.println("Running test -> testMethod1");
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod2() {
        System.out.println("Running test -> testMethod2");
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod3() {
        System.out.println("Running test -> testMethod3");
    }
}
```

Code for SomeClassToTest

```
package appcode;

public class SomeClassToTest {

    public int sumNumbers(int a, int b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }
    
}
```

log -

```
[RemoteTestNG] failed to get TestNG version from class: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version "[WORKING]": non-numeric "[WORKING]"
[RemoteTestNG] now trying to parse the version from pom.properties
[RemoteTestNG] now trying to parse the version from MANIFEST.MF
[RemoteTestNG] parsing TestNG version at jar:file:///C:/Users/Flemin/OneDrive/Documents/testng/testng-7.4.0.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class appcode.TestAnnotation
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:30)
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.instantiateUsingDefaultConstructor(InstanceCreator.java:193)
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstanceUsingObjectFactory(InstanceCreator.java:113)
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstance(InstanceCreator.java:79)
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.dispense(SimpleObjectDispenser.java:25)
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.internal.objects.GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.dispense(GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.java:30)
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:112)
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:165)
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:122)
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:102)
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:94)
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:59)
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:463)
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:339)
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:292)
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:223)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:33)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:66)
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.ITestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(ITestRunnerFactory.java:55)
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:659)
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:173)
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:107)
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1300)
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1276)
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1125)
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public appcode.TestAnnotation() accessible: module TestNGTutorial does not "exports appcode" to module org.testng
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException(AccessibleObject.java:387)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:363)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:311)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.checkCanSetAccessible(Constructor.java:192)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible(Constructor.java:185)
    at org.testng@7.4.0/org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:22)
    ... 29 more
```